# rails sunspot nokogiri dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I am trying to follow the wiki instructions for getting sunspot on rails

https://github.com/outoftime/sunspot/wiki/Adding-Sunspot-search-to-Rails-in-5-minutes-or-less

Everything works fine until when I do:

```
$ rake sunspot:solr:start
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- nokogiri
```

However, it looks like I DO have nokogiri installed:

```
$ gem list 
....
nokogiri (1.4.4)
....
```

Anyone have any thoughts?  I'm on a mac if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you including nokogiri in your Gemfile or environment.rb?

For rails 3 add this line to your Gemfile

```
gem 'nokogiri'
```

For rails 2 add config.gem to your environment.rb

```
config.gem "nokogiri"
```

It's also quite possible if you're using Rails 3 that your `gem list` command doesn't reflect the directory where bundler has installed the gems for your app.

Comment: adding gem 'nokogiri' did it! Thanks!